# Disable the side menu's swipe to open gesture for Login page (or any page) in Ionic 2

Tags: menu, angular, ionic2

I'm new  to Ionic 2 & Angular2 and I have downloaded a new Ionic template with the following command

```
 Ionic start appname sidemenu --v2 --ts
```

For  this  particular  solution I  have  added a  login page  to validate a user. Once the validation  succeeds the user will be navigated to the menu page which uses the side menu.

As the  solution  is  based  on the `sidemenu` template, the side menu is showing  on the login page whenever the user swipes left.

So can somebody please guide me to rectify this mistake and stop the side menu from showing when the view is swiped.

**My code**

App.ts file

```
import {App, IonicApp, Platform,MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HelloIonicPage} from './pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import {ListPage} from './pages/list/list';
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';


@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
class MyApp {
  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    private app: IonicApp,
    private platform: Platform,
    private menu: MenuController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Hello Ionic', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'My First List', component: ListPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    let nav = this.app.getComponent('nav');
    nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

app.html file

```
  <ion-menu side-menu-content drag-content="false"   [content]="content">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="#p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Homepage.ts file (login page in this case).

```
   import {Page, Events,Alert,NavController,Loading,Toast,Storage,LocalStorage,SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from 'angular2/common';
import {HelloIonicPage} from '../hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

 public Uname :string;
 public usrvalid:boolean;
 public usrpwd :boolean;
 public usrpwdlength:boolean;
 public usrvalidlength:boolean;
 public isUnchanged:boolean;
 public usrpwdzero:boolean;
 public usrvaliddigits:boolean;
 rootpage:any;

public Upwd:string;
  constructor(public nav:NavController) {
this.nav=nav;
this.isUnchanged=true;
var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})");

// rootPage: any = HomePage;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the `drag-content` directive is used in ionic 1, for Ionic 2 what you can do is disable it from within your page class file.

You can do this by importing the `MenuController` provider from `ionic-angular` and then call the `.swipeEnable(shouldEnableBoolean, menuId)` method to disable the swipe gesture within your page's class (this is also documented [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/#swipeEnable)).

Your login controller should be something like this...

```
import {Page, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public menu: MenuController) {
        this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
    }
}
```

If you have multiple menus and each one has an id then you can target a specific menu like this...

```
this.menu.swipeEnable(false, `menuId`);
```

Comment: For anyone having trouble getting swipeEnable(false) to work, it's likely because your menu hasn't yet been initialized. If you try doing this on the Hello Ionic template, it won't work in the constructor but will inside the `platform.ready().then` block

Comment: I'm having same situation like questioner, I did my code like your answer. But, after login I navigate to Page A, but it didn't have menu bar icon in there. Then, I slide to open menu list, I click that page again, then suddenly it have menu bar icon. I put this `this.menu.swipeEnable(false);` in Page A controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false, 'left');
}

Comment: For the down voter... at the time of answering this was a working solution so instead of just down voting maybe edit my answer with the more up to date solution so it will be helpful to others :)

Comment: Actually swipeEnable work if I swipe from very corner! I want swipe from every where on page for open menu. is any way except adding swipeleft event? @Will.Harris

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/enable sidemenu at any time at any page by calling

$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)

e.g:

angular.module('ABC').controller('xyzCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)
```

});