# Only disable swipe to open ion-menu, not swipe to close Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I found the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652827/disable-swipe-to-view-sidemenu-ionic-2) really helpful but found that it also disables the swipe to close gesture.

Is there any way to have it only disabled for opening the menu, not closing it? I find it a little unresponsive when trying to close it and think that the swipe gesture would fix it. I can't find anything in Ionic docs regarding it.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [swipeEnabled]="false">...</ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *default* way to do that in Ionic, but you could use the `ionOpen` and `ionClose` callbacks to handle when the swipe feature should be enabled or disabled:

1. Enable the swipe feature after opening the menu, so it can be used for closing the menu
2. Disable the swipe feature after closing the menu, so it can't be used for opening the menu

### **[Working plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipe-menu-enable-on-close)**.

---

### **View**

```
<ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="content" 
(ionOpen)="enableSwipe()"     <!-- Enable it when opening  -->
(ionClose)="disableSwipe()">  <!-- Disable it when closing -->
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>Side menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>    
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

### **Component**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    public rootPage: any = HomePage;

    constructor(private menuCtrl: MenuController) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.disableSwipe();
    }

    public enableSwipe(): void {
      this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(true);
    }

    public disableSwipe(): void {
      this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted!